Colors changed after JPEG to PNG conversion using PIL
My Lambda function uses the Python Image Library (PIL) to convert images, specifically converting everything to PNG. Recently, I've run into a few cases where the colors of the image noticeably change during the conversion from JPG. Could you advise me on what I should do?
Original JPG
Converted PNG
def convert_image (s3_source_key, prefix):
    playout_key = prefix + '_playout.png'
    thumbnail_key = prefix + '_thumb.png'
    all_good = False

    try:
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

        # read the original file
        file_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=S3_SOURCE_BUCKET, Key=s3_source_key)['Body']
        file_buffer = file_object.read()

        im_orig = Image.open(BytesIO(file_buffer))

        # save to png (even if original is actually a png)
        buffer = BytesIO()
        im_orig.convert('RGBA').save(buffer, 'PNG', optimize=True)

        buffer.seek(0)
        s3_client.put_object(Body=buffer, Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=playout_key)

        # create a thumbnail for an image asset
        im = Image.open(BytesIO(file_buffer))

        width, height = im.size
        new_w = width / 3 # 3 is a default resize coefficient
        new_h = height / 3
        
        im = im.convert("RGBA")
        im = im.resize((int(new_w), int(new_h)))
        buffer = BytesIO()
        im.save(buffer, 'PNG')
        buffer.seek(0)
        
        s3_client.put_object(Body=buffer, Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=thumbnail_key)

P.S. I tried converting to RGB instead of RGBA, but the colors are still changing.
I also tried to save the PNG with the 'optimized' flag set to 'False.
Also, I tried preserving the color profile.
Still no luck...

I tried to have a look at the images with a different program which warned me that the color format of the .jpg is CMYK. From what I remember colors of CMYK and RGB images can appear to be pretty different on the screen. You wrote that this occurres only in a few cases. Are these all CMYK images?

@Flow, thanks for checking. And yes, that's right - all the problematic images are in CMYK. I need them to be converted to RGB or RGBA (for the PNG files)

For what it's worth: It does seem like PIL ignores the embedded color profile, and uses some generic CMYK to RGB conversion in this case. I get similar result in my own software (Java), if I disable the ICC profile conversion. I don't know PIL in detail, but maybe there is a way to force an ICC profile conversion? PS: Preserving the profile makes no sense if you convert the data from CMYK to RGB, as the profile will only work with CMYK input... And PNG can only store RGB(A) data anyway.

@AlexOat It seem like this answer might help you though I was not able to test it due to missing icc profiles which I also cannot install where I am right now. Here you find a thorough explanation of where to get extra profiles that might help to make the above mentioned link a working solution for you.

Converting JPEG to RGBA is nonsensical because alpha is incompatible with JPEG. It looks like your library is not using the K channel at all. There is no standard way to do CYMK=>RGB conversion. CYMK in JPEG is pretty much an Adobe only thing. One approximate way is to do C+K, Y+K, M+K=>RGB.
